# Can you specify 6-digit unicode escape format for UTF-8?

Tags: postgresql, utf-8, escaping

Can I specify a 6-digit unicode escape format for a character in UTF-8?

Example: U& \+000061

Or can that be used only for UTF-16?

Comment: In what programming language?

Comment: Postgres SQL, but does that matter?

Comment: Different programming languages have different rules about escape characters, if they even support them. Please edit your question to include a tag for postgres.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to specify a Unicode escape in a PostgreSQL string literal: lowercase `\u` for 4 hexadecimal digits and upper case `\U` for eight digits.

```
SELECT E'\u00A9';

 ?column? 
══════════
 ©
(1 row)

SELECT E'\U0001D11E';

 ?column? 
══════════
 
(1 row)
```

So no, there is no way to use exactly 6 digits, but `\U` should work for you.